# Missing location or location status

Tags: android, google-play-services

I recently updated `Google Play Services` to version 43. Updated from version 10.0 of library to 11.0 in `gradle`, so I can [reduce friction with new Location APIs](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html). Using following code:

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client =
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( this );
        
        if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
        {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        client.requestLocationUpdates( LocationRequest.create(), new LocationCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult( LocationResult locationResult )
            {
                
                double lat = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                double lng = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                
                Log.d( "LOCATION_XYZ", "onLocationResult: Latitude:" + lat + " Longitude:" + lng );
            }
    @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability( LocationAvailability locationAvailability )
            {
                super.onLocationAvailability( locationAvailability );
            }
        }, null );
```

For once the code is working fine, then all of a sudden app crashes continuously with stack trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Missing location or location status: 556648763, 554464808, 553821978, 560939479
                                                    at anza.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509430:214)
               

                                 at anyz.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11509430:18)
                                                at mme.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509430:6)
                                                at mmo.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509430:25)
                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                at mrv.run(:com.google.android.gms@11509430)
                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This does not give any hint as to why this is happening, by looking at it, when I see **`gms`** in logs, I assume the error is inside `Google Play Services`. But I dont know how to resolve it. I tried searching SOF, but this problem is not listed by anyone, at least what my search results shown.

Has anyone else facing the issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: I had the same issue but this error gone by adding Internet permission in manifests

Comment: I have added them already.